# Flutter Firebase Children Count

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I'm currently creating a dashboard application for my main application, this dashboard is able to display in charts the demography of the users that uses the app. I use Firebase Database as the backend. The JSON tree of my DB is as shown below. My question is, how do I get the amount of data with a specific value of a key? Example: the number of children with the value 'Pria' for the key 'jk' is 2.

My Backend JSON Tree:

[image: My Backend JSON Tree]

So far, I'm able to get all of the data using:

```
DatabaseReference itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('data_pengguna');
```

And I've also tried the codes below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
int jmlPria;
FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child('data_pengguna')
    .orderByChild('jk')
    .equalTo('Pria')
    .once()
    .then((onValue) {
  Map data = onValue.value;
  jmlPria = data.length;
});
```

But I haven't successfully filtered the data and put it inside a variable, can anyone help me?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That last snippet looks correct, `jmlPria` should have the number of children. What's the problem with it?

Comment: When I try to output it using `Text(\`$jmlPria\`)` it returns a `null`, even when I tried instantiating and setting the value of `jmlPria` inside the `State` declaration and also the `build` function. Any idea what's wrong with my code @FrankvanPuffelen ?

Comment: Make sure that ``Text(`$jmlPria`)`` is **inside** the `then()` callback. Outside of that, `jmlPria` will not have the correct value.

Comment: Ooh, I see. Now it works just as I've expected. Thank you very much for the help @FrankvanPuffelen :)

Comment: Great to hear! I wrote it into a short answer, so we can close things off nicely for others trying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last snippet looks correct, `jmlPria` should have the number of children.

But the value of `jmlPria` will only be set to the latest value *inside* the `then()` callback. Make sure that `Text(`$jmlPria`)` is inside the `then()` callback. Outside of that, `jmlPria` will not have the correct value.

Also see [Doug's great blog post on asynchronous programming](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93).